# Next tag badge score is frozen and not updating

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-score, badge-progress

When you look at my [activity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/users/967/bleh?tab=topactivity) on Mythology.SE, it says in the "Next tag badge" progress that the [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) score is 5:

> [image]

However, my actual tag score, if you slide down, is 13:

> [image]

Is it something I hadn't noticed? A bug?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The badge progress sometimes freezes. If you change which tag badge you're tracking and then switch back to it again, it should update (if you don't want to wait for a fix).

Comment: @Shadow-Wizard thanks